# Convert Excel range into csv or tab-delimited file

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlwings

I have an Excel 2016 worksheet `Sheet1` and would like to convert the range `$A$1:$Z$150` into a csv or tab-delimited file.

I am using python v3 xlwings to capture the range.

```
my_range = Range('Sheet1','A1:Z150').value
```

How do I convert `my_range` into a csv or tab-delimited file using python?

A tab-delimited file is same as copying the range and pasting it onto a text file. This is actually my preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding of xlwings is correct, then `my_range` should be a nested list object. In this case the following code suffices to write the data to a CSV file with tabs as delimiter.

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerows(my_range)
```